# What does a character of a scheme mean?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, projective-varieties, serre-duality

Here is a soft question I met in the book *Introduction to Grothendieck Duality Theory* by [Altman and Kleiman](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0060932).

In Chapter I the proposition 2.1 uses a term called "a character of $X$" where $X$ is a quasi-projective scheme over any field.

I'm wondering what does this terminology mean. I checked Hartshorne's introductory book and all the EGA's yet not find anything coinciding with this.

The following are the original pieces from Altman&Kleiman's book:

> 1.3. Grothendieck Duality. Let $k$ be a field, $P=\mathbb{P}_k^n$ be the projective n-space over $k$, and $X$ a closed subscheme of pure dimension $r$. Let $F$ be a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, $\omega_P=\mathcal{O}_P(-n-1)$ and $\omega_X=\mathscr{Ext}_{\mathcal{O}_P}^{n-r}(\mathcal{O}_X,\omega_P)$. Then an isomorphism $\eta_P: H^n(P,\omega_P)\to k$ defines a map $\eta_X: H^n(X,\omega_X)\to k$, which composed with the Yoneda pairing, yields a pairing $$ H^p(X,F)\times\text{Ext}_{\mathcal{O}_X}^{r-p}(F,\omega_X)\to k.$$
> 2.1 Under the condition of 1.3, the pair $(\eta_X,\omega_X)$ is a **character** of $X$, uniquely determined up to unique isomorphism.

Comment: Looks like this is the definition of a character.

Comment: @Sasha could you be more specific? It seemingly doesn't coincide the usual definition of [characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(mathematics)) or Chern characters.

Comment: It looks like they suggest to call the pair $(\eta_X,\omega_X)$ a **character**, and there is no reason to think that this has any relation to group characters or Chern characters (in the same way as Chern characters have no relation to group characters).

Comment: Perhaps A&K meant an *invariant*, which indeed is.

Comment: @Sasha: I see. so this word is basically "mathematically" meaningless.

Comment: @LeoAlonso: Now I get it. Maybe the word "intrinsic thing" or "functorial thing" or "invariant" instead of "character" is better since there're already mathematical meanings for characters.